# Sorting a Map by key using values from another Map

Tags: java, sorting, collections, dictionary

I know there are a lot of similar questions, but I think my case is quite special, and I haven't really found a proper answer that helps me, so here it goes.

I have a `Map<Integer,List<String>>` with the Integer being a kind of grouping by `type` and the Strings list being the `elements` in that type. Each `element` in a `type` can have an `order` value assigned to it (which is not saved in the List by default), so I've made a `Map<Integer, List<Integer>>` which consists of the `type` as key and an `element order` list as values.

I want to sort the 1st Map by keys, but the values of those keys should be the lowest value from the List for the same key in the 2nd Map. I'm trying to do this by using `Collections.sort()` with a custom Comparator, but I'm a bit lost as to how exactly to achieve that. Here's the unfinished Comparator code:

```
 private class sortComparator implements Comparator {

    private Map<Integer, List<String>> grouped = null;
    private Map<Integer, List<Integer>> sortOrder = null;

    public sortComparator(Map<Integer, List<String>> grouped, Map<Integer, List<Integer>> sortOrder){
        this.grouped = grouped;
        this.sortOrder = sortOrder;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {

        return 0;
    }
    //get the lowest value from the values connected to a key
    private Integer sortGroups(Map<Integer,List<Integer>> sortOrder, Integer key){
        List<Integer> calcTypeOrder = sortOrder.get(key);
        Iterator orderIterator = calcTypeOrder.iterator();
        Integer firstElement;

        Collections.sort(calcTypeOrder);
        if (orderIterator.hasNext()){
            firstElement = (Integer)orderIterator.next();
        } else firstElement = 0;
        return firstElement;
    }
}
```

I'm quite uncertain how exactly to procede or if I'm even on the right track. I hope I was able to explain what I'm trying to do.
EDIT: More explanations as requested:

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> grouped
//Map<Type, List<ElementNames>>
//consists of elements, which look like this
Map.EntrySet<13, List<Template 1, Template 2>> //1st entry
Map.EntrySet<24, List<Something, Something Else>> //2nd entry
Map.EntrySet<1, List<Example, Example, Example>> //3rd entry
Map.EntrySet<35, List<More Things>> //4th entry
```

That information doesn't help me order the map, however I can get an `ordered` property from the database, which is set for Template 1 and Template 2 (in the current case). So I make another Map, with those entries:

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> sorted
//Map<Type, List<ElementOrder>>
//consists of elements, which look like this
Map.EntrySet<13, List<3, 4>> //1st entry
Map.EntrySet<24, List<1, 2>> //2nd entry
Map.EntrySet<1, List<6, 7, 8>> //3rd entry
Map.EntrySet<35, List<5>> //4th entry
```

So basically I want the order in the 1st Map to be based on the values in the 2nd Map. In the current case, the lowest value for the 2nd EntrySet's values is 1, and the lowest value for the 1st EntrySet's values is 3, meaning that in the 1st Map, they have to switch places. Here's how it should look after the sort. **Keep in mind that I've got both maps with all their entries before I start sorting, and their key/value pairs are equal, because they refer to properties of entries in a database.**

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> groupedAfterSort
//Map<Type, List<ElementNames>>
//consists of elements, which look like this
Map.EntrySet<24, List<Something, Something Else>> //1st entry
Map.EntrySet<13, List<Template 1, Template 2>> //2nd entry
Map.EntrySet<35, List<More Things>> //3rd entry
Map.EntrySet<1, List<Example, Example, Example>> //4th entry
```

Comment: since the types are Integer and String, can you make some meaningful examples? like what do you have as input and what result do you want to have after sort. I've read your question and your codes, cannot understand what do you want.

Comment: Ok, I'll add more explanations.

Comment: Can you write a code snippet that, given 2 objects, can report which should come first in sorted order?  If not, there isn't much point to trying to USE that logic to actually sort.

Comment: Why don't you create a class that has a String and an Integer to properly represent your objects and save those?

Comment: You _cannot_ sort `Map<Integer, T>` by anything unless it is an instance implementing the `SortedMap` interface. In the latter case you should use a comparator to alter standard sorting of integers, but to help you a couple of sensible examples of desired sorting order for some sample data are essential. Having said that you will only be able to use a comparator that takes keys, not the values into account for a `SortedMap` so the best you can do is to turn your map into a list of pairs and define a comparator for that structure, but again data examples needed.

Comment: @OlegS. I was thinking of converting it to a TreeMap or something that can use the comparator.

Comment: @Schadenfreude As I mention above it will not work: the comparator is on keys only and is invoked any time you add an element. So you can hardly make it use values and as soon as the second map changes in any way, if you use it in the comparator, the sorting of the first map will not update. If you really need keys along side of values, you would need a list of pairs. But really _do explain_ properly what your sorting should look like on examples and you are likely to get a solution (for a list of pairs or for a sorted map that uses something else than int as keys)

Comment: Generally when you're talking about sorting a Map you're confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be simple. Just create a custom comparator and refer to the sort order list. For example the `sortMap` method will do what you are looking for.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;


public class MapSorter2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Integer, List<String>> grouped = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();
        grouped.put(13, new ArrayList<String>() {{ add("Template 1"); add("Template 2"); }});
        grouped.put(24, new ArrayList<String>() {{ add("Something"); add("Something Else"); }});
        grouped.put(1, new ArrayList<String>() {{ add("Example"); add("Example"); add("Example"); }});
        grouped.put(35, new ArrayList<String>() {{ add("More Things"); }});

        Map<Integer, List<Integer>> sorted = new HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>();
        sorted.put(13, new ArrayList<Integer>() {{ add(3); add(4); }});
        sorted.put(24, new ArrayList<Integer>() {{ add(1); add(2); }});
        sorted.put(1, new ArrayList<Integer>() {{ add(6); add(7); add(8); }});
        sorted.put(35, new ArrayList<Integer>() {{ add(5); }});

        Map<Integer, List<String>> sortedGrouped = sortMap(grouped, sorted);
        System.out.println(sortedGrouped);
    }

    private static Map<Integer, List<String>> sortMap(
            Map<Integer, List<String>> unsortedMap, Map<Integer, List<Integer>> sortOrder) {

        List<Entry<Integer, List<String>>> list = new LinkedList<Entry<Integer, List<String>>>(
                unsortedMap.entrySet());

        Collections.sort(list,
                new Comparator<Entry<Integer, List<String>>>() {

                    @Override
                    public int compare(Entry<Integer, List<String>> o1,
                            Entry<Integer, List<String>> o2) {
                        Integer key1 = o1.getKey();
                        Integer key2 = o2.getKey();
                        Integer sortObj1 = sortOrder.get(key1).get(0);
                        Integer sortObj2 = sortOrder.get(key2).get(0);
                        return sortObj1.compareTo(sortObj2);
                    }
                });

        Map<Integer, List<String>> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, List<String>>();
        for(Entry<Integer, List<String>> item : list){
            sortedMap.put(item.getKey(), item.getValue());
        }
        return sortedMap;
    }

}
```